# A matching opposite of the word "axiom"

Tags: ancient-greek

A [rough search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom) told me that the word *axiom* traces back to axíōma (ἀξίωμα), which roughly means *"that which commends itself as evident"*. I am looking for a word which expresses the dual concept to an axiom, i.e. *"that which commends itself as absurd"*. Are there any good fits for this?

Comment: Posting a comment since you seem to want a single Greek-derived word, but in logic that would be best expressed as an 'axiomatic falsehood' or something similar. It would be equivalent to saying that the negation of the statement is an axiom.

Comment: I don't have time to look now, but Aristotle's *Metaphysics* Γ (=bk. 4) dedicates a large section to showing the absurdity of those who deny the principle of non-contradiction. I'm sure "atopon" and "geloion" make several appearances.

Comment: The Euclid term is [ἄτοπον  atopon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ἄτοπος)   absurd, used in *reductio ad absurdum*  εἰς ἄτοπον ἀπαγωγή.

Comment: https://math.wikia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum

Comment: @dbmag9 My question indeed derives from logic. The reason is there are weaker logics without negation / falsehoods. And similarly to declaring truths, in those logics it is necessary to declare falsehoods. Therefore and am indeed looking for a word that would sum up "axiomatic falsehood".

Comment: BTW "That which commends itself as evident" isn't actually a very good translation of ἀξίωμα -- that word literally means "something requested/demanded/expected" (as opposed to something that has to be proved).

Comment: @TKR Though that's the literal meaning, it comes to have a more specific sense in logical works, at least as far back as Aristotle, e.g. *Posterior Analytics* A.2.72a16-18. In fact, it is precisely because an axiom *can't* be proved that it is "demanded" as evident. In Aristotle's terminology, it's "immediate" (ἄμεσον).

Answer (score 1):

[Ἀξίωμα](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%80%CE%BE%CE%AF%CF%89%CE%BC%CE%B1) doesn't really mean "that which commends itself as evident." Without mathematical context, it means something like "that which is worthy." The root is the verb [ἄγω](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%84%CE%B3%CF%89), which mainly means to lead (like a military leader), but in the context of logical propositions  the idea is more like to weigh, i.e., ἀξίωμα is basically "something weighty."

Cosmas Zachos says in a comment that [ἄτοπος](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%84%CF%84%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%82) is used as the adjective in Euclid to mean absurd, but as far as I know there is no attested noun form. [Ἀπορία](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%80%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%81%CE%AF%CE%B1#Ancient_Greek) is a noun meaning an impossibility. Literally, it means something that we can't pass through (cognate with "porous"), or something that we try and doesn't work.

Greek tends to be very free with creating new words using prefixes, e.g., modern Greek has σκυλοβαρετό, which means dog-boring. This kind of thing is especially fruitful with prepositions. The adverb ἀξίως has an antonym ἀναξίως, so I think it would be perfectly natural to say ἀναξίωμα as an antonym of ἀξίωμα. However, this word doesn't seem to be attested. I think a Greek would consider the meaning to be obvious, something like "that which is unworthy" or "something that doesn't carry weight." In a similar vein, we have ἀλόγως=unreasonably, so we could say ἀλόγωμα=that which is unreasonable.

Comment: Two comments: (1) Ἀξίωμα comes most directly from ἀξιόω. I'm not sure if there is a deeper connection to ἄγω, but that isn't the verb that would first come to mind. (2) I don't really like "impossibility" as a translation of ἀπορία. In philosophical contexts, it means a "puzzle" or "difficulty." (In fact, a huge point of Plato's *Meno* is that it *isn't* impossible to get past an ἀπορία.)

Comment: It also seems pretty evident to me that the OP *is* asking about a logical/mathematical context, so I'm confused by the resistance to his (pretty plausible) literal translation of ἀξίωμα to show how it came to mean "axiom." LSJ lists this logical meaning and translates the parent meaning as "that which is thought fit."

Comment: @brianpck: Thanks for your comments. The etymology tracing back through ἄχιος  to ἄγω is from wiktionary. Beekes' entry for ἄχιος seems to confirm this is standard, although he suggests there is room for doubt.